# how to install mqtt library on AWS lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

i want to publish a **mqtt** message from **AWS** lambda function, i tried this

```
`exports.handler = function(event, context) {
// TODO implement
context.done(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com');


 var state = 'closed';

 client.on('connect', () => {
 console.log("connected to broker");
 // Inform controllers that garage is connected
 client.publish('garage/connected', 'true')
 })
 };
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a zip file with the node_modules directory and the source file for your lambda.

e.g.

```
lamdba.js
node_modules/mqtt
node_modules/mqtt/package.json
...
```

You should use npm to install the package locally.

The details are described in the Lambda documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)